# Assembly Language nested loops

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16

As I'm new to this language, it might sound really noob-ish but this came in my exam the other day and I'm really desperate to know the answer.

According to my inner programmer, I think the result will be:

> EAX = 280

All help will be appreciated. **What is the final value of EAX register for the following program?**

```
mov eax, 0 
mov ecx, 10 
loop1: 
mov ecx, 5 
mov eax, 3 
loop2: 
add eax, 5 
jmp loop2 
jmp loop1
```

Comment: What's stopping you from running it and seeing for yourself? Also, are you sure that's the correct code? Since it has `jmp loop2` there will be no "final value", it's an endless loop with `eax` continually incremented by 5.

Comment: Exactly that's what I surmised but as the question states, it has to have a final answer.

Comment: There is none, it's an endless loop.

Comment: even if the `jmp` instruction would be replaced by `loop` (which makes sort of sense, considering there is `ecx` being set up ahead of loop), the `loop2` part would execute 5 times, then at `ecx == 0` the another `loop loop1` would be executed, which would jump back to `loop1` label, which would reset `ecx` back to 5, so it would be again infinitely cyclic situation. It may be difficult generally to tell when the code will stop (see "halting problem"), but in this case the CPU state is repeated only after few billlions of instructions (till same `eax`), and it's easy to see how it will repeat.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure how you can find that the program will stop at EAX=280.

From you code, you will have the following instructions executed:

```
1:     mov eax, 0 
2:     mov ecx, 10 

loop1: 
3:     mov ecx, 5 
4:     mov eax, 3 
loop2: 
5:     add eax, 5 
6:     jmp loop2 
7:     add eax, 5
8:     jmp loop2
9:     add eax, 5
...
```

As you have no condition, the program will never stop and will forever increment `eax` by 5 and jump to `loop2`
The branch to `loop1` will never be executed.

Comment: Does that mean it'll stop at EAX = FFFFFFFF

Comment: @Zextro: No... This is an infinite loop. `EAX` will roll over because the register is only 32 bits wide. (as in: `0x0000_0000 == 0x1_0000_0000 & 0xFFFF_FFFF`)